# VS2010 debugger won't step into WCF Service locally hosted

Tags: .net, wcf, debugging, service, breakpoints

I have a simple "Hello World" WCF Service hosted on my local machine in the ASP.NET Development Server. A client C# console application (NET 4.0 / 4.03) calls the service to get a "Hello World". Can't be any simpler.

Everything was fine and beautiful: The service worked and I could step via F11 or via breakpoints from the client into the WCF service...

Then I had a problem with two Win7 updates that constantly wanted to reinstall. Following advice from the web, I used a DotNet Cleanup Tool ([here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=27e6a35d1a492af7&id=27E6A35D1A492AF7!390)) to remove the .NET framework. After reinstalling the .NET framework(s) and all updates everything seemed to be fine: No more update reinstalls, NET is working, debugger is working, everything OK... with one exception:

**The VS debugger will not step anymore into my WCF service!**

The following things are **not working**:

- I already reinstalled SP1 for VS2010
- compilation debug="true" is correctly set in web.config
- There is no problem with x86/x64 (it worked before)
- I can manually attach to the WebDev.WebServer40.exe and debug into the service, but this sucks if you have to do it often

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Seems trivial but have you recompiled your WCF service and then updated your reference in your C# application?  You may also try removing your application from IIS and adding it again, thought it sounds like IIS is working since you can manually attach to it.

Comment: what is your local server ? local IIS, IIS Express or WebDev.WebServer40.exe ? It is not the same. If so select another in Web TAb under project properties.

Comment: Im using WebDev.WebServer40.exe and there is no IIS installed on my development machine.

Comment: I recompiled service and client several times (including a manual delete of old obj and bin folders) and also updated the service reference.

Comment: are you running visual studio as admin or have you disabled UAC?